# Change script to stop returning non-prime numbers and only return primes

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have the below script that returns each number stating whether it is prime or not and asking the user if they wish to see the next number in sequence. I wish to make a change so that the script does **not** produce a print statement for the non-prime numbers and instead skips them and only returns the next prime number, after which asks if the user wished to see the next prime.

Here is my code:

```
def prime_number():
    game_on = True
    count = 3
    while True:
        for num in range(2, count):
            if (count % num) == 0:
                print(count,"is not a prime number")
                break
        else:
            print(count,"is a prime number")
        question = input("Would you like to see another prime number?? Please enter Yes or No: ")
        if question[0].lower() == "y":
            count = count + 1
            continue
        return
```

When I run this and select Yes a few times I get the below. I want to skip the non-prime numbers altogether and get rid of the non-prime print statements below. I have tried a few ways of ignoring the non-primes in the above while loop but non have worked so far.

```
3 is a prime number
Would you like to see another prime number?? Please enter Yes or No: Yes
4 is not a prime number
Would you like to see another prime number?? Please enter Yes or No: Yes
5 is a prime number
Would you like to see another prime number?? Please enter Yes or No: Yes
6 is not a prime number
Would you like to see another prime number?? Please enter Yes or No:
```

Comment: "and instead skips them and only returns the *next* prime number" - What exactly do you mean by `next` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another proposal close to yours:

```
def prime_number():
    number = 3
    while True:
        if all(number % num != 0 for num in range(2, number)):
            print(f"{number} is a prime number")
            response = input("Would you like to see another prime number?? Please enter Yes or No: ")
            if response[0].lower() == "n":
                return
        number += 1
```

Remarks:

1. Why starting with `3`? `2` is the first prime.
2. There are way more efficient ways to compute primes (e.g., you could check only up to `sqrt(number)`), but I didn't want to change your algo. I doubt it really matters for this use case.

Comment: No specific reason starting at 3. I just needed to code the script to give the next highest prime regardless of starting point. Thanks for the above, this works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a list then looping through your for in range loop adding each prime to the list then loop through your list printing all primes to a Given Number.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I get it. You can just do this:

```
def next_prime(n):
    while True:
        for denom in range(2, n//2):
            if n % denom == 0:
                n += 1
                break
        else:
            return n

def prime_number():
    game_on = True
    p = 2
    while True:
        p = next_prime(p + 1)
        print(p)
        question = input("Would you like to see another prime number?? Please enter Yes or No: ")
        if question[0].lower() == "y":
            continue
        return
```